# Getting JSON Array values Within a JSOn Object and Use In Class Object

Tags: android, json, class, parsing

I am trying to populate a class object with JSON data, and I keep getting this error

> org.json.JSONException: No value for machinereports

Here is the sample json file, I am trying to use

```
{
"id" : 1,       
"reports": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "For Reorder",
        "subtitle": "Report Name",
        "date": "Monday, Aug 08, 2016",
        "machinereports": [
            {
                "name": "Reorder List",
                "count": "9"
            },
            {
                "name": "Reorder List Critical",
                "count": "9"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code I am trying to retrieve and populate my class object with

```
public class Report {
public String id;
public String title;
public String subtitle;
public String date;
public ArrayList<String> machinereports = new ArrayList<>();

public static ArrayList<Report> getReportsFromFile(String filename, Context context) {
    final ArrayList<Report> reportList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Load Data
        String jsonStr = loadJsonFromAsset("reports.json", context);
        JSONObject jsonOne = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray reports = jsonOne.getJSONArray("reports");


        // Get Report objects from data
        for(int i = 0; i < reports.length(); i++) {
            Report report = new Report();

            report.id = reports.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
            report.title = reports.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
            report.subtitle = reports.getJSONObject(i).getString("subtitle");
            report.date = reports.getJSONObject(i).getString("date");

            // Get inner array listOrReports
            JSONArray rList = jsonOne.getJSONArray("machinereports");

            for(int j = 0; j < rList.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jsonTwo = rList.getJSONObject(j);
                report.machinereports.add(jsonTwo.getString("reportName"));
               /* report.machinereports.add(jsonTwo.getString("count"));*/
            }
            reportList.add(report);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return reportList;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out, where I am having the problem, when I step through, when it gets to second JSONArray object it goes to the catch exception.

Comment: Shouldn't `JSONArray rList = jsonOne.getJSONArray("machinereports");` be something like `JSONArray rList = reports.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("machinereports");`? The `machinereports` array is at the same level as `title`, `date` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSON` does not have a field named `reportName`.

```
report.machinereports.add(jsonTwo.getString("reportName"));
```

change it to

```
report.machinereports.add(jsonTwo.getString("name"));
```

Also with the answer from @comeback4you you have the wrong call to the `JsonArray`.

```
 JSONArray rList = jsonOne.getJSONArray("machinereports");
```

Should be

```
JSONArray rList =  reports.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("machinereports");
```

Comment: Murat the same problem, is happening even after I changed the the field from reportName to name.

Comment: @PsyChotic You had the wrong call to JsonArray. I edited it

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONArray rList = jsonOne.getJSONArray("machinereports");
```

change to

```
JSONArray rList =  reports.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("machinereports");
```

and inside for loop change below

```
report.machinereports.add(jsonTwo.getString("name"));
```